# give numbering to each div with same class name

Tags: jquery

I have around 10 `div` elements with same class name e.g.

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div1"></div> <!-- and so on.... -->
```

I want to give numbering to each `div` e.g.

```
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div1">2</div>
<div class="div1">3</div>
<div class="div1">4</div>
<div class="div1">5</div>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Is the duplicated 5 a bug or a feature ?

Comment: @dystroy - Good question... I just edited it out without considering that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('.div1').html(function(i){ return i+1 });
```

See [documentation of the html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [demonstration](http://jsbin.com/agufij/1/).

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
$('.div1').each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8EtM6/1/)

Comment: index()+1, to start from 1, rather than 0. :)